# How to install packages into a virtual environment from another virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

Given how large Python packages can get, if this is possible, it would save a lot of bandwidth used in downloading the wheels.

Comment: Anaconda certainly works in this way. If you create a new virtual environment, it only downloads any packages (or versions of packages) that have not previously been downloaded by conda.

Comment: @DavidBuck Does conda pull an updated package in presence of a little outdated package in another environment? If so, is there a way to tell conda to relax the pull and use the existing packages automatically, without having to specify exact version?

Comment: I can’t say I’ve ever tried to that level of specificity, but to be honest I would doubt if there’s any sort of ‘pick the nearest rather than download the specific package’ option